# How to wait for a function to finish its execution in angular 2.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-promise

Below is my code, I want `login()` and `authenticated()` functions to wait for `getProfile()` function to finish its execution. I tried several ways like promise etc. but I couldn't implement it. Please suggest me the solution.

```
import { Injectable }      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { myConfig }        from './auth.config';

// Avoid name not found warnings
declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
  // Configure Auth0
  lock = new Auth0Lock(myConfig.clientID, myConfig.domain, {
    additionalSignUpFields: [{
      name: "address",                              // required
      placeholder: "enter your address",            // required
      icon: "https://example.com/address_icon.png", // optional
      validator: function(value) {                  // optional
        // only accept addresses with more than 10 chars
        return value.length > 10;
      }
    }]
  });

  //Store profile object in auth class
  userProfile: any;

  constructor() {
    this.getProfile();  //I want here this function to finish its work
  }


  getProfile() {
    // Set userProfile attribute if already saved profile
    this.userProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));

    // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
    this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult) => {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);

      // Fetch profile information
      this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (error, profile) => {
        if (error) {
          // Handle error
          alert(error);
          return;
        }

        profile.user_metadata = profile.user_metadata || {};
        localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
        this.userProfile = profile;
      });
    });
  };

  public login() {
    this.lock.show();
    this.getProfile();  //I want here this function to finish its work
  };

  public authenticated() {
    this.getProfile();  //I want here this function to finish its work
    return tokenNotExpired();
  };

  public logout() {
    // Remove token and profile from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
    localStorage.removeItem('profile');
    this.userProfile = undefined;
  };
}
```

Comment: your getProfile function should return a promise/observable and then login and authenticated will be able to connect to the promise/observable and performs actions once it is done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like you saw in the comments, you have to use `Promise` or `Observable` to achieve this, since your behaviour is pretty simple, you should use `Promise` because `Observable` will have a lot of features you don't need in this case.

Here is the `Promise` version of your service:

```
import { Injectable }      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { myConfig }        from './auth.config';

// Avoid name not found warnings
declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
  // Configure Auth0
  lock = new Auth0Lock(myConfig.clientID, myConfig.domain, {
    additionalSignUpFields: [{
      name: "address",                              // required
      placeholder: "enter your address",            // required
      icon: "https://example.com/address_icon.png", // optional
      validator: function(value) {                  // optional
        // only accept addresses with more than 10 chars
        return value.length > 10;
      }
    }]
  });

//Store profile object in auth class
userProfile: any;

constructor() {
    this.getProfile();  //I want here this function to finish its work
  }


getProfile():Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>(resolve => {
    // Set userProfile attribute if already saved profile
    this.userProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));

    // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
    this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult) => {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);

      // Fetch profile information
      this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (error, profile) => {
        if (error) {
          // Handle error
          alert(error);
          return;
        }

        profile.user_metadata = profile.user_metadata || {};
        localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
        this.userProfile = profile;
        resolve()
      });
    });
   })
};

public login(): Promise<void>{
    this.lock.show();
    return this.getProfile();  //I want here this function to finish its work
  };

  public authenticated():void{
    this.getProfile().then( () => {  
        return tokenNotExpired();
    });
  };

  public logout():void {
    // Remove token and profile from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
    localStorage.removeItem('profile');
    this.userProfile = undefined;
  };
}
```

More on `Promise` [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/release-notes/typescript-1.7.html)

Comment: I'm getting following warning and its still not working:-
lock.min.js:2 (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

Comment: This is not an error but a warning, you have a possible memory leak because you added too much listeners, you should check your code quality (you often find this kind of error because of listeners created in loops).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you set up getProfile to return an observable. Then your other functions can subscribe to that function and do their actions in the subscribe function. The [Angular 2 HTTP tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) gives an example of this